# How can I open another view in WPF MVVM using click handlers and commands? (Is my solution reasonable?)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling, viewmodel

I am writing a WPF application that has two windows.

I have a `MainWindowViewModel` that holds two more view models: `AllTagsViewModel` and `PlotViewModel`.

```
public AllTagsViewModel AllTagsViewModel { get; private set; }

public PlotViewModel PlotViewModel { get; private set; }
```

At the moment, I'm using this solution as a click handler in the main window:

```
private void LaunchPlotWindow_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlotWindow.GlobalInstanceCount == 0)
        {
            PlotWindow plotWindow = new PlotWindow();

            PlotViewModel context = GetViewModel().PlotViewModel;
            plotWindow.DataContext = context; 

            plotWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

I am also binding a command to the button. The command is in the `MainWindowViewModel` and it instantiates a new PlotViewModel using the constructor `PlotViewModel(AllTagsViewModel atvm)`.

The problem with this is that the command setting the data context executes after the click handler. this means that the `PlotWindow` works as expected the second time it is opened.

What is a better solution for this problem? Can I use an event to keep the `AllTagsViewModel` in the `PlotViewModel` up to date at all times with the one in the `MainWindowViewModel`? My solution at the moment feels like a hack and very poor practice.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Foreword: 
Usually you wouldn't want to have your PlotViewModel and pass it to a window, as it makes a few things more complicated.

There are to basic approaches View-First and ViewModel First. In View-First you create the View (Page, Window etc) and inject the ViewModel into it (usually via constructor). Though this makes it a bit difficult to and pass a parameter object to it.

Which is where the NavigationService comes. You resolve the View via IoC container, then pass a parameter to the ViewModel, i.e. if it's a `UserViewModel` you'd pass the `userId` to it and the ViewModel will load the user.

The solution: Navigation Service
You can either use an existing one (Prism, or other MVVM Frameworks which come with their own navigation services).

If you want a own simple one, you could create an `INavigationService` interface and inject it into your ViewModels.

```
public interface INavigationService 
{
    // T is whatever your base ViewModel class is called
    void NavigateTo<T>() where T ViewModel;
    void NavigateToNewWindow<T>();
    void NavigateToNewWindow<T>(object parameter);
    void NavigateTo<T>(object parameter);
}
```

and implement it like (I am assuming you use a IoC container, since IoC is a key to MVVM to key the objects decoupled. Example with Unity IoC Container)

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    public NavigationService(IUnityContainer container) 
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public void NavigateToWindow<T>(object parameter) where T : IView
    {
        // configure your IoC container to resolve a View for a given ViewModel
        // i.e. container.Register<IPlotView, PlotWindow>(); in your
        // composition root
        IView view = container.Resolve<T>();

        Window window = view as Window;
        if(window!=null)
            window.Show();

        INavigationAware nav = view as INavigationAware;
        if(nav!= null)
            nav.NavigatedTo(parameter);
    }
}

// IPlotView is an empty interface, only used to be able to resolve
// the PlotWindow w/o needing to reference to it's concrete implementation as
// calling navigationService.NavigateToWindow<PlotWindow>(userId); would violate 
// MVVM pattern, where navigationService.NavigateToWindow<IPlotWindow>(userId); doesn't. There are also other ways involving strings or naming
// convention, but this is out of scope for this answer. IView would 
// just implement "object DataContext { get; set; }" property, which is already
// implemented Control objects
public class PlotWindow : Window, IView, IPlotView
{
}
```

and finally you implement your `PlotViewModel` class and use the passed parameter to load the object

```
public class PlotViewModel : ViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, INavigationAware
{
    private int plotId;
    public void NavigatedTo(object parameter) where T : IView
    {
        if(!parameter is int)
            return; // Wrong parameter type passed

        this.plotId = (int)parameter;
        Task.Start( () => {
            // load the data
            PlotData = LoadPlot(plotId);
        });
    }

    private Plot plotData;
    public Plot PlotData {
        get { return plotData; }
        set 
        {
            if(plotData != value) 
            {
                plotData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlotData");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course could modify the `NavigationService` to also set the `DataContext` inside it. Or use strings to resolve the View/Window (such as Prism for Windows Store Apps does).

And in the final code you open the window by calling `navigationService.NavigateToWindow<IPlotView>(platId);` in your code (i.e. in an `ICommand` which is bound to a buttons `Command` Property in your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has the possibility of creating a `PlotWindow` without the existing `PlotViewModel` if you use the `CanExecute` of your `CreatePlotViewModelCommand`.

To avoid that problem I would bind the `MainWindowView` to the `PlotViewModel` property defined inside the `MainWindowViewModel`. That way you will get informed once it changes and you can set up a template creating the corresponding view. The ViewModels could than easily be created using a command and the view will only be created if a ViewModel exists.