# Pass parameter to a constructor in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I am building a WPF browser application with MVVM pattern.

I have a first page (ConsultInvoice) with a dataGrid. When I double click on one of the row I want to navigate to another page (EditInvoice) passing the selected row in argument to my constructor.

I know if I want do things properly I should use a dependency injection, but I don't really see how to use it here.

How can I simply pass this constructor?

**ConsultInvoiceViewModel**

```
private Invoice _selected;
public Invoice Selected
{
    get
    {
        return _selected;
    }
    set
    {
        _selected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
    }
}

private void Edit()
{
    EditInvoiceViewModel editInvoice = new EditInvoiceViewModel(Selected); 
   /* doing something here*/
}

public ICommand EditCommand
{
    get
    {
        return editCommand ?? (editCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.Edit(), p => this.CanEdit()));
    }
}
```

**EditInvoiceViewModel**

```
public class EditInvoiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Context ctx = new Context();
    Invoice invoice;
    PreInvoice preInvoice;
    #region properties
    private ObservableCollection<PreInvoice> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<PreInvoice> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return collection;
        }
        set
        {
            collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public EditInvoiceViewModel(Invoice inv)
    {
        /* do stuff*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm slightly confused. Aren't you already passing a parameter (Selected) to a constructor (EditInvoiceViewModel(Invoice inv)) in the ViewModel (ConsultInvoiceViewModel)? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Rowbear yeah, but the goal it's to open a new EditInvoiceView.xaml and it does accept only a default constructor. So what I am trying to do doesn't work.

Comment: ah! I see. Are you planning to have EditInvoiceView show as a popup, or a new window? How do you plan to control showing EditInvoiceView? With just .Show()/.ShowDialog()? Would it make sense for all the possible invoices from  ConsultInvoiceViewModel to share one view? Or will you be able to edit multiple invoices at once?

Comment: @Rowbear, I'm planning to show it as a new window, but a popup is fine as well. And after I don't know really how to navigate. This is the point. Between my others pages I use Hyperlink. But now I need to pass 'Invoice' in argument to my constructor so I cannot use Hyperlink anymore. I just want to edit invoices one by one.

Comment: @Cantinou. Is it alright to keep a default constructor in EditInvoiceView and adding a public property of type EditInvoiceViewModel in EditInvoice. So you build withh a default constructor, and assign the property on the following line.

Comment: Using parameterless ViewModel constructor inside Views is pretty bad imho, as you can't easily inject services into it. Consider using Microsoft's Prism approach and resolving the ViewModel via ViewModel locator. Gives way more flexibility and is navigation aware (see answer below, based on Prism but you can reimplement it)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should avoid passing such parameters into the ViewModels constructor, as wiring it with Inversion of Control/Dependency Injection becomes a pain. While you can use Abstract Factory pattern to resolve objects with runtime parameters, it's imho not suitable for ViewModels.

Instead I always suggest using a form of navigation pattern, similar to how Microsoft's Patterns & Practices team has done with Prism. There you have an `INavigationAware` interface which your ViewModels can implement. It has 2 methods, `NavigateTo` and `NavigateFrom`.

And there is a navigation service. The navigation service will switch the views and before switching calling `NavigateFrom` in the current ViewModel (if it implements it. One can use it to check if data is saved and if necessary cancel the navigation. After the new View has been loaded and the ViewModel assigned to it, call `NavigateTo` in the newly navigated ViewModel.

Here you'd pass the parameters required for the ViewModel, in your case `invoiceId`. Try avoid passing whole models or complex objects. Use the `invoiceid` to fetch the invoice data and to populate your editing ViewModel.

A basinc implementation from my former answer (can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817827/how-can-i-open-another-view-in-wpf-mvvm-using-click-handlers-and-commands-is-m/28834777#28834777)):

```
public interface INavigationService 
{
    // T is whatever your base ViewModel class is called
    void NavigateTo<T>() where T ViewModel;
    void NavigateToNewWindow<T>();
    void NavigateToNewWindow<T>(object parameter);
    void NavigateTo<T>(object parameter);
}

public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    public NavigationService(IUnityContainer container) 
    {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public void NavigateToWindow<T>(object parameter) where T : IView
    {
        // configure your IoC container to resolve a View for a given ViewModel
        // i.e. container.Register<IPlotView, PlotWindow>(); in your
        // composition root
        IView view = container.Resolve<T>();

        Window window = view as Window;
        if(window!=null)
            window.Show();

        INavigationAware nav = view as INavigationAware;
        if(nav!= null)
            nav.NavigatedTo(parameter);
    }
}

// IPlotView is an empty interface, only used to be able to resolve
// the PlotWindow w/o needing to reference to it's concrete implementation as
// calling navigationService.NavigateToWindow<PlotWindow>(userId); would violate 
// MVVM pattern, where navigationService.NavigateToWindow<IPlotWindow>(userId); doesn't. There are also other ways involving strings or naming
// convention, but this is out of scope for this answer. IView would 
// just implement "object DataContext { get; set; }" property, which is already
// implemented Control objects
public class PlotWindow : Window, IView, IPlotView
{
}

public class PlotViewModel : ViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, INavigationAware
{
    private int plotId;
    public void NavigatedTo(object parameter) where T : IView
    {
        if(!parameter is int)
            return; // Wrong parameter type passed

        this.plotId = (int)parameter;
        Task.Start( () => {
            // load the data
            PlotData = LoadPlot(plotId);
        });
    }

    private Plot plotData;
    public Plot PlotData {
        get { return plotData; }
        set 
        {
            if(plotData != value) 
            {
                plotData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlotData");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of the `INavigationAware` interface used in Prism can be found on the [projects github repository](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Regions/INavigationAware.cs).

This makes it easy to pass parameter and `async` load your data (where there isn't any clean way to do this via constructor, as you can't `await` an `async` operation inside the constructor without locking, and doing this kind of things in the constructor is **very** discouraged).