# MVVM adding a list from a static service into the view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have created a service (static methods), which will get for instance all folders within google drive and returning a `List<File>`. (those methods are async [MSDN Async Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx))

The problem is I dont know how to pass my results into the view. I tried to using a ObservableCollection but I cant make it work.

And one more thing is that Im not sure if its in my usage useful.
I dont add one item or delete one item. I just scrap the whole folders every refresh. What I have understood is that this is useful for a collection of data which will edited by the user.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var service = DriveHelper.createDriveService("client_secret.json", false)
        // ERROR
        _googleDriveFolders = new NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>>( DriveHelper.getFiles(service), "trashed=false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"));
    }

    public NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>> googleDriveFolders { get; private set; }

    private ObservableCollection<File> _googleDriveFolders;
    public ObservableCollection<File> googleDriveFolder
    {
        get { return _googleDriveFolders; }
        set
        {
            _googleDriveFolders = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
//...
```

Comment: Can you show how you bind the ObservableCollection in the xaml? I assume you have tested if the collection gets filled, so if it's not showing the problem will probably be in the xaml.

Comment: The problem is that I have to convert Task<List<File>> into ObservableCollection<File>

Comment: If you call a async function that returns a Task<List<File>> you need to await that method to get the List<File> of which you can make a ObservableCollection. If, for some reason, you can not await the method you can also do MyTask.Wait(); List<File> MyList = MyTask.Result;

Comment: Your issue is that the the task returns immediately and `RaiisePropertyChanged()` is called before the loading is finished. Also don't do async operations in the constructor. Third and last, don't use static methods as a service, you got to use Dependency Injection and Inject the services via Constructor otherwise you violate the MVVM and create a strong coupled code (which is in violation of MVVM as one of it's goals is loosely coupled code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the issue is that your `NotifyTaskCompletion` immediately returns and gets assigned to the `refreshFoldersCommand` (btw. in C# naming conventions properties are in Pascal Case aka Camel Uppercase, not Camel lower case notation) property and the event is raised up immediately and not after the async operation finishes.

It's very bad practice to put `async` code into the ViewModels constructor (or any constructor for that case), because inside a constructor you can't `await` the `async` method.

There is no easy solution for it. The correct solution requires you to change your applications architecture and make use of a navigation service. I've posted it a few times already here on StackOverflow.

Prism (Microsoft's MVVM Framework) does come with a clean solution. It has an `INavigationAware` interface, that contains 3 methods (`OnNagivatedTo`, `OnNavigatedFrom` and `IsNavigatioNTarget`). To async load data into your ViewModel, `NavigateTo` is the important one.

In Prism it is called, after the previous View was unloaded (after calling `NavigateFrom in the former ViewModels class) and the newly one has been instantiated and assigned to the new View. Parameters passed to the`NavigationService.Navigate(..)`method are passed to`OnNagivatedTo` method of the ViewModel.

It can be marked as `async` and you can put your code there and await it

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>> googleDriveFolders { get; private set; }

    private ObservableCollection<File> _googleDriveFolders;
    public ObservableCollection<File> googleDriveFolder
    {
        get { return _googleDriveFolders; }
        set
        {
            _googleDriveFolders = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext context) 
    {
        var service = DriveHelper.createDriveService("client_secret.json", false)
        // ERROR
        googleDriveFolder = await DriveHelper.getFiles(service), "trashed=false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'");
    }
...
}
```

**Edit:**
Further answers about the same issue: 
[Pass parameter to a constructor in the ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33671936/455493)

[How can I open another view in WPF MVVM using click handlers and commands? (Is my solution reasonable?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28834777/455493)

**Edit 2:**
Also, you are assigning your `NotifyTaskCompletion` to `_googleDriveFolders` which is your backing field for the `googleDriveFolder` property, hence the `RaisePropertyChanged();` is never called.

**Edit 3: **
As of your code from that tutorial, your code isn't exactly following the tutorial. The guy in the tutorial is binding to the property `NotifyTaskCompletion`. You are binding it to the backing field though.

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    var service = DriveHelper.createDriveService("client_secret.json", false)
    // your property is named googleDriveFolders, but you are assigning it to _googleDriveFolders
    googleDriveFolders = new NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>>( DriveHelper.getFiles(service), "trashed=false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"));
}
```

This code, when complete, won't call `RaisePropertyChanged("googleDriveFolder")` (which is your observable list), because `NotifyTaskCompletion` will only refresh it's own property. It's very likely you have bounded your View to the `googleDriveFolder` (Observable property) rather than to `googleDriveFolders.Result`.

For this example it's imperative to bind to `googleDriveFolders.Result`, because the change notification will only get fired for the `Result` Property of the `NotificationTaskCompletition` object as seen in the examples code `propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));`.

So your XAML has to look something like

```
<ListView Source="{Binding googleDriveFolders.Result}"/>
```

But anyhows, the issue still remains, that it's bad practice to do async operations within the constructor, so even within your Unit Tests for example, it would start the async task everytime the object is initialized, so in every UnitTest even if you test different stuff and you can't pass parameters to it easily (like passing a link or a folder name which to load).

So the clean way is doing it via navigation service and an `INavigationAware` implementation for ViewModels that require it (modes that do not do any async operation just don't implement this interface).

Comment: Okay, you gave me some keywords which I will try to implement into my application( i dont want to use other frameworks). As I said ... I did it with a tutorial from msdn (link is above) where they putted the async method into a contructor inside the viewmodel. Maybe I explained it wrongly ... My Driveservice.getfiles is static and async and is awaiting a request from  google drive.

Comment: Of course you don't have to use a framework, but it's in many cases easier as it contains important tools for certain things (navigation, async loading after view switching, common bindable class, region support - used in navigation and a bunch of Behaviours, Action and Triggers to use inside XAML to solve common issues that are hard to solve otherwise). Prism is kind of the official Microsoft MVVM Framework, so it's a good choice for both personal and enterprise applications

Comment: Updated the answer with some more info on the implementation and the bits you were missing.

Comment: Mh do you know a way doing it without prism ? ... If not I will try it using prism

Comment: Well you can look at the PRISM github project and see how they done it and implement one yourself. But MVVM is a pretty complex ecosystem and unless you are making an application that consists of only one view and simple bindings, you will need some kind of framework (either writing own one and investing much work to find out the correct implementation without violating MVVM pattern) or using a matured MVVM Framework that has already done the hard work for you. It's under Apache 2.0 License so you can use it in commercial close sourced projects

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution ... But I think this isn't the best way. <.<
Using a Listview.

```
namespace UpdateUploader.ViewModels
{
using System.Windows.Input;
using Helper;
using Services;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    DriveService _service;
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _service = DriveHelper.createDriveService("client_secret.json", false);
        googleDriveFolders = new NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>>( DriveHelper.getFiles(_service, "trashed=false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"));
    }

    public NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>> _googleDriveFolders;
    public NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>> googleDriveFolders
    {
        get { return _googleDriveFolders; }
        set
        {
            _googleDriveFolders = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region ICommands
    private ICommand _refreshFoldersCommand;
    public ICommand refreshFoldersCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._refreshFoldersCommand == null)
            {
                _refreshFoldersCommand = new RelayCommand(p => this.loadFolders(p));
            }

            return this._refreshFoldersCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion ICommands

    public void loadFolders(object parameter)
    {
        googleDriveFolders = new NotifyTaskCompletion<List<File>>(DriveHelper.getFiles(_service, "trashed=false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"));
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

*NotifyTaskCompletion.cs*

```
namespace UpdateUploader.Helper
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    public sealed class NotifyTaskCompletion<TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public NotifyTaskCompletion(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult> task)
        {
            Task = task;
            if (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                var _ = WatchTaskAsync(task);
            }
        }

        private async Task WatchTaskAsync(Task task)
        {
            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChanged == null)
                return;
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCompleted"));
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsNotCompleted"));
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCanceled"));
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsFaulted"));
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Exception"));
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("InnerException"));
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ErrorMessage"));
            }
            else
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSuccessfullyCompleted"));
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));
            }
        }

        public Task<TResult> Task { get; private set; }
        public TResult Result
        {
            get { return (Task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) ? Task.Result : default(TResult); }
        }
        public TaskStatus Status { get { return Task.Status; } }
        public bool IsCompleted { get { return Task.IsCompleted; } }
        public bool IsNotCompleted { get { return !Task.IsCompleted; } }
        public bool IsSuccessfullyCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                return Task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion;
            }
        }
        public bool IsCanceled { get { return Task.IsCanceled; } }
        public bool IsFaulted { get { return Task.IsFaulted; } }
        public AggregateException Exception { get { return Task.Exception; } }
        public Exception InnerException
        {
            get
            {
                return (Exception == null) ? null : Exception.InnerException;
            }
        }
        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return (InnerException == null) ? null : InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

*DriveService.cs*(excerpt; createDriveService, getfiles)

```
namespace UpdateUploader.Services
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
    using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
    using Google.Apis.Upload;

    class DriveHelper
    {
        private static bool _unique;

        public static DriveService createDriveService(string passFilePath, bool createUniqueID)
        {
            _unique = createUniqueID;

            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(passFilePath))
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("keyfile not found...");
                return null;
            }

            string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }; // Full accces

            // loading the key file
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("client_secret.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/update-uploader");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Update Uploader",
            });
            return service;
        }

        // search = null ; get all files/folders
        public static async Task<List<File>> getFiles(DriveService service, string search)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<File> Files = new System.Collections.Generic.List<File>();
            try
            {
                // list all files with max 1000 results

                FilesResource.ListRequest list = service.Files.List();
                list.MaxResults = 1000;
                if (search != null)
                {
                    list.Q = search;
                }

                FileList filesFeed = await list.ExecuteAsync();

                while (filesFeed.Items != null)
                {
                    foreach (File item in filesFeed.Items)
                    {
                        Files.Add(item);
                    }

                    // if it is the last page break
                    if (filesFeed.NextPageToken == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    list.PageToken = filesFeed.NextPageToken;

                    filesFeed = list.Execute();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return Files;
        }
```

*ViewModelBase.cs*

```
namespace UpdateUploader.Helper
{
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // new since 4.6 or 4.5
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}