# Way to prevent dependencies for ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0

For instance, I have a ViewModel for a View inside a popup control.

ManagerView.xaml

```
<Popup Name="Popup1" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AGrid}" StaysOpen="True">
    <Popup.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPopupVisible}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Popup.Style>
        <View:AssignView></View:AssignView>
    </Popup>
```

AssignViewModel.cs:

```
    public AssignViewModel()
    {
        Default = this;
    }
    public static AssignViewModel Default;
    private ICommand iCloseCommand;
    .
    .
    .
    private void Close()
    {
        ManagerViewModel.Default.IsPopupVisible = false;
    }
```

And the ManagerViewModel also accesses the AssignViewModel. I pass parameters by assigning each of the ViewModels a static instance of themselves. This works well, but of course there is a dependency issue, but this is also because they actually depend on each other's values.

Can anyone suggest a design where I wouldn't have any dependencies? This is just an actual example of a ViewModel relying on another ViewModel which I encounter often, and I am trying to figure out a way to decouple them.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what you are trying to do finally ? Dependencies can be removed using events. For example, if I want some change in a TextBox by pressing a Button, I would do so by handling Click event and changing TextBox state there.

Comment: Sorry, how does using events remove dependencies? It will in any case break my MVVM pattern though. I'm updating my question for clarity...

Comment: Use interface, and when a Popup is opened, store Popup instance in interface type variable. Then you can close this Popup easily by invoking interface method. IPopup popup = Popup1; popup.Close();

Comment: I am wondering why you would want a `IsPopupVisible` property. It makes no sense to me. You could use the `Activity` pattern on the Popup class, or alternatively you can use a EventAggregator/MessageBus pattern, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first step is to remove the singleton pattern. Singleton is considered an anti-pattern for several reasons that are out of scope of the answer.

Singleton ViewModels (via static accessor at least, having a single instance of it managed by your dependency injection container is fine) violate one of the MVVM concepts of being loosely coupled.

To be be able to decouple them, you need the Inversion of Control (IoC) pattern and preferably an IoC Container which manages this dependencies (you can also do it without an IoC container, but it will be much harder to do so). You would inject your dependency chain via Constructor, i.e.

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    private readonly IMessageService messageService;

    public MainViewModel(IMessageService messageService) 
    {
        if(messageService == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("messageService");
        }

        this.messageService = messageService;
    }


    private void AssignUser(int userId)
    {
        this.messageService.Send<AssignUserMessage>(
            new AssignUserMessage() 
            {
                UserId = userId
            }
        );
    }
}
```

With that being said, we also come to the next topic, the message service. The message service will be a service for publishing and subscribing to events, similar to the `EventHandler` in C#/.NET, but truly decoupled. `IMessageService` is just an example here, but there are many messageservices available out there.

I personally use Prism for private and Enterprise level applications, as it comes with the basics required for MVVM (navigation with region support, messaging, binding & notifications and support for multiple platforms like WPF, Silverlight, UWP/WinPhone and Xamarin more recently). It has a steep learning curve at the beginning, but is very powerful once you get the grip of it.

The above code will send a notification message which can be accessed from other ViewModels, i.e.

```
public class AssignUserViewModel 
{
    private readonly IMessageService messageService;
    private readonly IUserRepository users;

    public AssignUserViewModel(IMessageService messageService, IUserRepository userRepository) 
    {
        if(messageService == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("messageService");
        }

        if(userRepository == null) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userRepository");
        }

        this.messageService = messageService;
        this.users = userRepository;

        // register to the AssingUserMessage here
        this.messageService.Register<AssignUserMessage>(OnAssignUserMessage);
    }

    private void OnAssignUser(AssignUserMessage message)
    {
        var user = await users.GetByUserIdAsync(message.UserId);
        // display your user and whatever you want to assign it and once done, 
        // save the changes, then send a notification that the user has been updated
        this.messageService.Send<UserAssignedMessage>(
            new UserAssignedMessage() 
            {
                UserId = user.Id
            }
        );
    }
}
```

This way both ViewModels are decoupled. `MainViewModel` do not know about the existence of `AssignUserViewModel` and vice versa. `MainViewModel` will just send a notification that a user needs to be be assigned and the `AssingUserViewModel` will react on it.

When things get more complicated, you may also require a navigation service, that will navigate (switch views or open a new window, etc.) to a view and pass the required parameters to it, but that's another topic. You'd usually inject your navigation service in the same was as the message service.

For examples on how to use navigation service, check out my other replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665346/pass-parameter-to-a-constructor-in-the-viewmodel/33671936#33671936) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817827/how-can-i-open-another-view-in-wpf-mvvm-using-click-handlers-and-commands-is-m/28834777#28834777).

MVVM can be pretty complex, once you go beyond a single ViewModel with a single View, as most tutorials on this topic are limited to.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the one way data flow.
The IsPopupVisible can be mapped to some state in the Model, ManagerViewModel can listen the state change from Model and change its own property while AssignViewModel can change the state of the shared Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Activity` pattern.

```
public class PopupResult
    : IViewModel
{
    //Some code
}

public class ActivityRunner
{
    public Task<PopupResult> Do<PopupResult>()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<PopupResult>();
        var view = new Popup();
        var model = new PopupResult();
        view.DataContext = model;
        view.Close += (e, o) => tcs.SetResult(model);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}


async void ShowPopupThenDoSomething()
{
    PopupResult result = await IActivityRunner.Do<Popup>();
    //Do something when we close
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aron, but I am on C# 4 (no async), and I am also using the MVVM pattern. Having the Popup control on code will break it...

Comment: @Tyress Actually the first time I had seen this pattern was in a .net 4.0 MVPVM project. The trick is to use a ServiceLocator to instanciate the view for the IViewModel, when you are using WPF. As for .net 4.0, you'd only need it for the async await, which is not mandatory.

Comment: @Tyress However you should not be developing for .net 4.0 at this point in time. Microsoft are dropping .net 4.0 in a matter of weeks (16th Jan) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/framework_faq

Comment: Please note, that C# 4.0 (and 5.0, 6.0 for that matter) are fully backwards compatible with .NET 2.0. That means you can write your code using let's say C# 5.0 or 6.0 syntax (including async/await) and still compile against .NET 4.0 or 3.5 Framework as the TPL (Task Parallel Library) is available since .NET 3.5 (as 3rd party assembly and since 4.0 natively as part of .NET 4.0 framework). All you need is a C# 5.0 or 6.0 compiler, which usually comes with newer Visual Studio (2012 and 2015 respectively) Versions

Comment: And unless you don't need the Visual Studio Enterprise features and your company qualifiers for the community edition, using Visual Studio Community Edition is free of charge. https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547